# My android emulator is running MAUI app extremely slowly

Tags: visual-studio, performance, maui

Spent all weekend updating Visual Studio to 17.4.3. Removed my old Android Simulator -- had to clear up space for the upgrade because my 128GB SSD got filed up.

Anyways, trying out the Maui framework, run the new Welcome app on Android Simulator (pixel 5 api 31). It takes a whopping full minute just for the emulator to boot up, and then another 1.5 minutes to deploy and finally see the welcome screen.

I do not think this is normal. I spent all night trying to enable hardware acceleration on the emulator, but I believe the HAXM options was always turned on.

Any tip for how I can tune up my android emulator performance? It was really fast before my MAUI upgrade when I used good-old Xamarin.

Comment: 1. You can try to enable the developer mode in the emulator: Settings->About emulated device-> click Build number 5 times. 2. What if you connected to a physical device, would that process be very slow?

Comment: i don't have an android phone lol. I have iphone but booting up my macbook for pairing is worse than android emu.

Comment: It would be a little bit tricky if you don't have an android phone. This is a performance issue for the emulator, you can go through [troubleshooting about performance-issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/troubleshooting?view=net-maui-7.0#performance-issues).